# Updating view base on user preferences

Tags: javascript, json

Am working on a school web project, i am trying to display a lecture time table base on the registered courses of a student in a given level, a comprehensive timetable(timetable with all subjects of various level) is made available and saved in a timetable.json file by an admin. How do i select the subjects and the various period they appear for a given student in a given level.

`#timetable.json file`

```
{
    "mon":{
        "1":["EEE104","","","",""],
        "2":["","EEE101","","",""],
        "3":["","","","","",""],
        "4":["","","","",""],
        "5":["","","","",""]
    },"tue":{
        "1":["","","","",""],
        "2":["","","","",""],
        "3":["","","","",""],
        "4":["","","","",""],
        "5":["","","","",""]
    },"wed":{
        "1":["","","","",""],
        "2":["","","","",""],
        "3":["","","","",""],
        "4":["","","","",""],
        "5":["","","","",""]
    },"thu":{
        "1":["","","","",""],
        "2":["","","","",""],
        "3":["","","","",""],
        "4":["","","","",""],
        "5":["","","","",""]
    },"fri":{
        "1":["","","","",""],
        "2":["","","","",""],
        "3":["","","","",""],
        "4":["","","","",""],
        "5":["","","","",""]
    }
}
```

in the above file, the abbreviated week days("mon","tue",..."fri") represents the various days in a week, while the numbers("1", "2", "3"..."5") represents
the various periods.

I am thinking of creating a separate json file for the student, testing every value in the timetable.json file and seeing if there subject exists, then i add it to the student json file. 
i feel my implementation is too demanding, is there a more elegant way of doing this, i just need a pointer, to a framework or any idea.

Comment: The json file that you have supplied doesn't contain any student information so what you want to do isn't achievable.

Comment: I intend querying my database to get the subject titles for the the given student @jeff

Comment: I would be creating a query that would retrieve the students course name, days and periods. Then when displaying the information is just a matter of filling in the blanks.

Comment: the kind of logic you're describing is best done in your database, as jeff suggests. Then you just build the end result into JSON. JSON is great for transmitting data in bulk from one system/process to another, it's not really intended for doing detailed querying and analysis.